# Rounding of very large floats in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

**Java**:

```
float big = (float) 1e12;
float ulp = Math.ulp(big);

float result = (big + 2/3*ulp) - big;
```

`result` is `0.0`, while I was expecting `ulp` (`65536.0`). Can somebody explain why?

Comment: do you want this :`(big + (2.0/3.0*ulp)) - big;`

Comment: Yes! actually constants division result must be (float) to avoid conversion error from double to float. Ironical mistake, since I commented on similar error 10 mn ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because 2/3 = 0 (integer division), try 2.0 / 3

Comment: Indeed! 2f/3f (is better to keep the compiler quiet). thanks!

Comment: @Approachingminimums It's enough to *explicitly* cast only one side, the other will be *implicitly* cast.

Comment: Then 2f/3 (to avoid double to float conversion error.)

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
float result = (big + 2f/3*ulp) - big;
```

ie, you need to typecast the division values else **integer/integer** will result to **zero**.

Answer (score 1):

Try **typecasting** either 2 or 3 to float and try, as **2/3=0**, thats why result=0.0